# i am not getting the updated record in datatable after saving the inline edits in lwc

Tags: lightning-datatable, refreshapex, inline-editing

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import getAccountNames from '@salesforce/apex/fetchKidsClubsName.getAccountNames';
import getKidsClubRecords from '@salesforce/apex/fetchKidsClubsName.getKidsClubRecords';
import UpdateChild from '@salesforce/apex/fetchKidsClubsName.UpdateChild';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import KCObject from '@salesforce/schema/Kids_club__c';
import statfield from '@salesforce/schema/Kids_club__c.status__c';
import { updateRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';



const columns = [
    { label: 'club name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text' },
    { label: 'staff number', fieldName: 'Staff_No__c', type: 'number', editable: true },
    { label: 'Maximum spaces', fieldName: 'Maximum_spaces__c', type: 'formula' },
    { label: 'spaces booked', fieldName: 'Spaces_booked__c', type: 'Number' },
    { label: 'spaces left', fieldName: 'Spaces_left__c', type: 'formula', cellAttributes: { class: { fieldName: 'spacesLeftClass' } } },
    { label: 'Date', fieldName: 'Date__c', type: 'date' },
    { label: 'Wait list', fieldName: 'Wait_list__c', type: 'Number', cellAttributes: { class: { fieldName: 'waitListClass' } } },
    { label: 'Status', fieldName: 'status__c', type: 'priorityPicklist', editable: true, wrapText:true ,
    typeAttributes:{
        options: {fieldName:'picklistOptions'},
        value: {fieldName:'status__c'}

    }},
];

export default class DropdownExample extends LightningElement {
    @track selectedOptions = [];
    @track options = [];
    @track columns = columns;
    @track selectedRows = [];
    @track data = [];
    @track draftValues = [];
    @track showTable = false;
    @track showOpenOnly = false;
    @track showTableDataForOptions = {};
    @track mystatus=[];
    refreshdata;
    // dateField1 = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
    // dateField2 = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];


    @wire(getObjectInfo,{objectApiName:KCObject})
    kcobjectmetadata;


    @wire(getPicklistValues,{recordTypeId:'$kcobjectmetadata.data.defaultRecordTypeId',fieldApiName:statfield})
    statpicklist({data,error}){
        if(data){
            this.mystatus = data.values;
            this.loadKidClubRecords();
           
        }
        else if(error){

        }
    }


    @wire(getAccountNames)
    wiredOptions({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.options = data.map(name => ({
                label: name,
                value: name
            }));
        } else if (error) {
            console.error('Error loading options:', error);
            this.showToast('Error', 'Failed to load options', 'error');
        }
    }

    @wire(getKidsClubRecords, { kidClubNames: '$selectedOptions', startDate: '$dateField1', endDate: '$dateField2', showOpenOnly: '$showOpenOnly' })


    wiredChildData(result) {
        this.refreshdata=result;
        if(result.finaldata){
            this.data = result.finaldata;

        }else if(result.error){
            console.log("error loading records");
        }

    }


    get showTableDataForAllSelectedOptions() {
        const tableData = [];
        this.selectedOptions.forEach((option) => {
            tableData.push({
                option: option,
                data: this.showTableDataForOptions[option]
            });
        });
        return tableData;
    }

  
    
    

    handleChange(event) {
        this.selectedOptions = event.detail.value;
        this.loadKidClubRecords();
    }


   

    handleDateField1Change(event) {
        this.dateField1 = event.detail.value;
        this.loadKidClubRecords();
    }

    handleDateField2Change(event) {
        this.dateField2 = event.detail.value;
        this.loadKidClubRecords();
    }

    handleShowOpenChange(event) {
        this.showOpenOnly = event.target.checked;
        this.loadKidClubRecords();
    }

   
   

    

   

    loadKidClubRecords() {
        if (this.selectedOptions.length > 0) {
            this.selectedOptions.forEach(option => {
                const kidClubName = option;
                getKidsClubRecords({
                    kidClubNames: [kidClubName],
                    startDate: this.dateField1,
                    endDate: this.dateField2,
                    showOpenOnly: this.showOpenOnly
                })
                .then(result => {
                    this.refreshdata = result;
                    let pickoptions =[];
                    for(var key in this.mystatus){
                        pickoptions.push({label:this.mystatus[key].label,value:this.mystatus[key].value});
                    }
                    console.log('Picklist Options:', pickoptions);


                    const dataForOption = this.showOpenOnly ?
                        result.filter(record => record.status__c === 'Open') :
                        result;

                    this.showTableDataForOptions[kidClubName] = dataForOption.map(item => {
                        let spacesLeftClass = item.Spaces_left__c < 0 ? "slds-theme_error" : "";
                        let waitListClass = item.Wait_list__c <= item.Spaces_left__c && item.Spaces_left__c !== 0 ? "slds-theme_success" : "";
                        waitListClass = item.Wait_list__c > item.Spaces_left__c && item.Spaces_left__c !== 0 ? "slds-theme_warning" : "slds-theme_success";
                        return { ...item, "spacesLeftClass": spacesLeftClass, "waitListClass": waitListClass, 'picklistOptions':pickoptions };
                    });

                    // Trigger a re-render to update the template
                    this.showTableDataForOptions = { ...this.showTableDataForOptions };
                    this.showTable = true;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error loading kid club records:', error);
                    this.showTableDataForOptions[kidClubName] = [];
                    this.showTable = true;
                });
            });
        } else {
            this.showTableDataForOptions = {};
            this.showTable = false;
        }
    }







    async handleSave(event) {
                const updatedValues = event.detail.draftValues;
                const recordIds = updatedValues.map(row => row.Id);
                if (updatedValues.length > 0) {
                    const updatedRecordsMap = {};
                    updatedValues.forEach((row) => {
                        updatedRecordsMap[row.Id] = row;
                    });
              
        
                    UpdateChild({ childData: updatedValues })
                        .then((result) => {
                            
                            
                            if(result==="Failed"){
                                this.showToast('Error', 'Failed because sys admin cannot do overbooking please update staff number', 'error');
                            }
                            else{
                                console.log(result);
                            this.showToast('Success! Please refresh the page for the updated results', result, 'success');
                            this.data = this.data.map((row) => ({
                                ...row,
                                ...updatedRecordsMap[row.Id],
                            }));
                          
                            
        
         
                             refreshApex(this.refreshdata);
                            
                       
                            
       
                           
                        }
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            this.showToast('Error', 'Please enter Open or Closed', 'error');
                        })
                        .finally(() => {
                            this.draftValues = [];
                            
                        });
                }
            }


    
   

    handleRowSelection(event) {
        this.selectedRows = event.detail.selectedRows;
    }

    showToast(title, message, variant) {
        const event = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: title,
            message: message,
            variant: variant,
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }
}
```